# Loading Models in same position, so that it overlays

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the `multimodel` loader of the Autodesk. When I load the same model to the viewer, the position of previous model shifts to a different position.

I'm using transformations, like translation,rotation and scaling, to adjust the position of the model so that is overlays over the first model. Is there a way to load the model in a way where it overlaps on loading the second model?

Also, for the z-oriented `rvt` and `nwc` files, is there a fix?

For reference, I have been following these blogs:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows-part-2-model-loader

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have another placement or offsets applied to loaded models while using the `ModelLoaderExtension`. If you just want to load the same model twice, 
here is a sample for you:

```
var models = [
  '123.svf',
  '123.svf'
];


function _onGeometryLoaded( event ) {
 if( urns.length <= 0 ) {
     viewer.removeEventListener(
       Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
       _onGeometryLoaded
     );
     return;
 }

 viewer.loadModel( urns[0], { globalOffset: event.model.getData().globalOffset } );
 urns.splice( 0, 1 );
}

viewer.addEventListener(
 Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
 _onGeometryLoaded
);

viewer.loadModel( urns[0] );
urns.splice( 0, 1 );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it worked for f3d files, but didn't work for (rvt & rvt) and (rvt & f3d), does type of the model matter?

Comment: Which one didn’t work fine on RVT and RVT? I tested my answer above with Revit models before posting here.

Comment: for other files it did work, but for the RVT files the models are apart from eachother

Comment: Could you provide a non-confidential reproducible case contained your Revit models and your minimum complete yet Forge Viewer app demonstrating this issue to forge.help@autodesk.com?

Comment: thanks, it worked, i guess the model i was trying had some kind of problem